# Create content types available in multiple site collections

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I want to create a content type, lets call it MyDocument with some properties we need.  However we have 10 departments each one with its own site collection.

I want all documents to be created using MyDocument,across all site collections.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SharePoint 2010, you can use a Content Type Hub.

From [Plan to share terminology and content types](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee519603.aspx):

> To share content types among site collections, you make one content type gallery the “hub” of a managed metadata service, create connections to the service from each Web application that contains a site collection, and specify that site collections should use the content types in the service.

The same effect can also be achieved using [a custom Feature](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010general/thread/b7a4630a-d309-4398-bd54-ee18b511e914/).